# how to get all information of wkt polygon when i click on it?

Tags: json, sql-server, openlayers, openlayers-3, wkt

I get the data from MSsql server 2012 in json format, i get just WKT string to convert for showing on the map using ol.format.WKT() .

I want to show the ID and the name of the polygon when i click, on popup.
How can i recognize in which polygon am i clicking?

How can i know the map in which polygon I click and get me the data of that polygon?

```
for (var i = 0; i < geometries.length; i++) {

    var feature = wktReader.readFeature(geometries[i].GeomCol1.Geometry.WellKnownText);

    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == 'Polygon') {
        feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'blue',
                width: 1
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
            })
       }));
       featureCollection.push(feature);
    }
}
```

this is a part how i get just wkt string.

[image: These are the polygons that i have shown, and i want to show a popup with the informations of the polygon which i click]
These are the polygons that i have shown, and i want to show a popup with the informations of the polygon which i click

[image: This is a picture of how i have stored the spatial data in my MSsql server]

This is a picture of how i have stored the spatial data in my MSsql server

Thanks

Comment: in OL terms, by polygon you mean "feature" or literally _the polygon of a feature_?

Comment: thanks for your interest, 
i am new to this and i am not very sure what is the difference between "polygon feature " and "polygon of a feature" ?

actually i have changed the question and want to know how to retrieve information of the polygon which i click.

thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEachFeatureAtPixel` ([api doc](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel)) can get you all the features on a certain position. Admittedly, it can be confusing to use. The callback you pass to that function is called for every layer. If the callback returns a truthy value, it stops and then *forEachFeatureAtPixel* returns whatever your callback returned. This makes it perfect to select a specific feature.

```js
var count = 2000;
var features = new Array(count);
var e = 4500000;
for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
  features[i] = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coordinates),
    myHappyAttribute: ('you are beautiful ' + i)
  });
}

var source = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: source});


const view = new ol.View({
  center: [2500000, 0], zoom: 5
});
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [ 
    new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    layer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view 
});


map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  const pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  const feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
    pixel,
    someFeature => someFeature, // return first element
    {
      hitTolerance: 2 // how far off the click can be
    }
  );
  if (feature) {
    const attr = feature.get('myHappyAttribute');
    console.log('clicked on feature with attr:', attr);
  } else {
    console.log('not clicked on a feature');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol-debug.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: I can get the coordinate of polygon corner like this "POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))", how can i use this response on this code
-----------------------
features[i] = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(coordinates),
    myHappyAttribute: ('you are beautiful ' + i)
  });
--------------------------

Comment: Your question was "how to recognize which polygon I clicked". That is shown in this answer. Just add additional attributes (eg the ID_nom) to the feature to which the geometry belongs and use `feature.get(attributeName)` to read your custom attributes.  myHappyAttribute is an example of such an attribute.

Comment: ok for my question is ok. but I have specified that I have data in wkt format

Comment: I am not sure how the wkt format handles custom attributes. The reader's code suggest that they are not used. But if they are, feature.get(attrName) should do the job. Maybe assign a random wkt feature to a global variable and then use the browser's debugger to inspect it's properties. (do not use console.log(feature), it blocks the browser because of self referencing loops). Or if you cant figure it out, provide a code sample with data